# Nose not executes setUpClass when run suite

Tags: python, python-3.x

Have Cases.py file with defined test suite:

```
def tests():
    setup = {
         'full': (
                 Clients.TestClients,
                 )
    }
    cases = os.getenv('testrun', 'full')
    all_tests = ()
    for case in setup[cases]:
        all_tests = itertools.chain(all_tests, TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(case))
    suite = LazySuite(all_tests)
    nose.run(suite=suite)
```

Also have class with defined methods and class(like template) for user:

```
class Admin(MainTemplate):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.login(cls.autotest_admin, cls.default_password)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.logout()
```

And file with tests:

```
class TestClients(Admin):

    def test_one(self):
         print(1)
```

If manually(from ide) run class, setUpClass would be executed
But if run Cases.py file, setUpClass would not be executed

What's wrong?

**UPD**:
i've just understood the same thing, that `TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(case)` could load only test_ functions, but not the all file with `setUpClass` method, could this be the true story?

How can i programmatically emulate running whole file (like from IDE) ?

Comment: Or is there any best practice to use?